# How to go from spreadsheet to MongoDB ddatabase (export and model)

Tags: mongodb, model

I am starting a new project, and I want to give mongodb a try. I have read a lot about it in the last few years, and have finally got a project to get started.

Although I have read a lot, I still have a little trouble fully understanding the model. I hope I can get a little help.

At the base of my project I have products, I got them in an spreadsheet format. This is what it look like:

[image]

There are a lot more brands, categories and types.

Now I was thinking about something like this, pretty much how I would model a mysql db:

```
brands = {
    id : ...,
    name : ...,
}

categories = {
    id : ...,
    brand_id : ...,
    name : ...
}

types = {
    id : ...,
    category_id : ...,
    name : ...
}

products = {
    id : ...,
    type_id : ...,
    code : ...,
    unit : ...,
    name : ...,
    price : ...
}
```

### The right model?

I was wondering if this is the best way to model this. Eventually the DB will be expanded with orders, stock etc.

### How to export this?

Another question is how to export this to mongodb. I have set up the server, and I have set up [Rock Mongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo) to have a phpmysql like interface. I haven't found any good import / export methods tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one mistake you're making is to try and normalize your data. Mongodb is all about denormalized data so that joins aren't necessary.

Comment: So would I then just store all the the articles as one-liners just as in the spreadsheet? Wouldn't this make it hard to manage when adding / changing brands and categories.

Comment: Yes and yes. You have the option to make separate collections, so for example I would probably make orders a separate collection from products. And you could probably use mingos map reduce to do bulk updates if you renamed a brand or something.

Comment: Denormalizing is a tradeoff to improve speed

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to look at Google Docs Spreadsheet and MongoDB. Since their programming API is Javascript/JSON I would suggest to give it a try.

You could write simple wrapper API for MongoDB to expose JSON data directly. Then importing it into Google Docs is super simple. Check out how MongoLab company did it:
https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-rest-api-for-mongodb

There are bunch of of REST API Interfaces available at:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface#HttpInterface-RESTInterfaces

Here is simple code using Google Script in Google Docs Spreadsheet:

```js
function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // query
  var q = {
    "field": "value"
  };

  var qStr = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(q));

  var url = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/xxxx/collections/eeeee?q=" + qStr  + "&s=&f=&view=json&apiKey=abababababababababab";

  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());

  var outArr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    var item = object[i];

    var cols = [];
    cols[0] = new Date(item['someDateObject']['$date']);
    cols[1] = item['brandName'];
    cols[2] = item['productName'];
    outArr.push(cols);
  }

  Logger.info(outArr);
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, outArr.length, outArr[0].length).setValues(outArr);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just published an article on exactly how to accomplish this integration. https://blog.mlynn.org/stitching-sheets/ This article walks you through creation of a simple Google App script which exports data via JSON objects to a MongoDB Database using MongoDB Stitch. Links to the github repo and gists are in the blog article. Hope this helps.